# Group dataframe by random event and set a new column with the group count

Tags: python, pandas

I've been struggling for a while trying to classify a dataset; maybe someone could help me or point in the right direction.

I have a dataframe with a bunch of events that happen one after the other, and at some random point, an event is registered in one of the columns. It looks like this:

```
       Timestamp         Event
0  10/26/2015 22:50:15     0
1  10/26/2015 22:50:46     0
2  10/26/2015 22:50:50     0
3  10/26/2015 22:50:51     0
4  10/26/2015 22:51:15     1
5  10/26/2015 22:51:47     0
6  10/26/2015 22:52:38     0
7  10/26/2015 22:54:46     1
8  10/26/2015 22:55:46     0
```

I need to create a new column that identifies each group of records that occur up to every occurrence or event '1'. And set a counter in that group. The result should be something like this:

```
       Timestamp         Event   Group
0  10/26/2015 22:50:15     0     1
1  10/26/2015 22:50:46     0     1
2  10/26/2015 22:50:50     0     1
3  10/26/2015 22:50:51     0     1
4  10/26/2015 22:51:15     1     1
5  10/26/2015 22:51:47     0     2
6  10/26/2015 22:52:38     0     2
7  10/26/2015 22:54:46     1     2
```

Please note that records that do now lead to a '1' event are ignored in the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cumsum()` on the `Event` column, which gives a new group id whenever `1` is encountered. Combined with `shift()`, you will be able to create the `Group` column as intended:

```
df['Group'] = df.Event.shift().cumsum().fillna(0) + 1

df.loc[df.index <= df.Event.iloc[::-1].idxmax()]   
# to filter trailing zero records
```

[image]

---

Another option:

```
g = df.Event.iloc[::-1].cumsum()
df.loc[g != 0, 'Group'] = g.max() - g + 1
df.dropna()
```

Comment: Thanks, @Psidom! Your answer works perfectly! Can I ask one more thing? What if the events are inverse numbers, '1' for the no event and '0' for the actual event?

Comment: You need to reverse it to this format with either `~df.Event` or `1 - df.Event`.

Answer (score 0):

```
df['Group'] = df.cumsum().drop_duplicates()
df['Group'] = df['Group'].fillna(method='bfill').astype(int)
df['Group'][0] = 1
```